# Sort elements in XML-file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
<xml>
 <person>
  <name>John</name>
  <age>33</age>
  <car>Yugo</car>
 </person>
 <person>
  <car>Tesla</car>
  <age>44</age>
  <name>Peter</name>
 </person>
<xml>
```

As some may notice the elements in  aren't in the same order.

Does anyone have know of an übersimple xslt that just preserves the xml-contents but formats the in-file?

This would be the wanted output:

```
<xml>
 <person>
  <age>33</age>
  <car>Yugo</car>
  <name>John</name>
 </person>
 <person>
  <age>44</age>
  <car>Tesla</car>
  <name>Peter</name>
 </person>
<xml>
```

A file that has the same values in it's elements BUT has some sort of order (in this case sorted by element-name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="person">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
<person>
    <name>John</name>
    <age>33</age>
    <car>Yugo</car>
</person>
<person>
    <car>Tesla</car>
    <age>44</age>
    <name>Peter</name>
</person>
</xml>
```

gives this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
<person>
    <age>33</age>
    <car>Yugo</car>
    <name>John</name>
</person>
<person>
    <age>44</age>
    <car>Tesla</car>
    <name>Peter</name>
</person>
</xml>
```

Comment: I tried running this solution as well (see my comment on how I run it) but I use saxon. It gives me an error with the code SXXP0003, something with welformed xml after the root-element

Comment: Hello Marko, I found this: http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200508/post60680.html Please try to add <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> at the beginning of your XML. Peter

Comment: I already have it there :( I have tried all sorts of things but this is still the error I get: SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed. I have tried googling it, but nothing concrete. What are you using to run the transformation?

Comment: Hello Marko, that is strange. Your XML is well-formed. I am using Xalan. Can you try changing your processor? I also tried Saxon6.5.5 and I got no error... I am using Oxygen XML Editor though.

Comment: I'll try changing to Xalan! I'll keep you posted! Thanks Peter!

Answer (score 3):

`xsl:sort` should do the trick when you tell it to sort by the value of `local-name()` function. Replace it with `name()` function if you want to account for namespace prefixes.

The following stylesheet copies all elements in literally any document and sorts their content alphabetically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="local-name()"></xsl:sort>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It does not accout for attributes, comments or CDATA but it shouldn't be a problem to implement these if you want.

Comment: May I ask how you run this? I downloaded a saxon.jar-file and I give it a java -jar saxon.jar -s:in.xml -xsk:xsl.xsl -o:out.xml and it gives me an error called SXXP0003 - I'm guessing you didn't run into this?

Comment: @marko I just included this style sheet in an XML document using the `<?xml-stylesheet ... ?>` processing instruction and opened it with Opera 12.0 The browser applied the XSL correctly. Oxygen and STS seem to do it properly as well.